# Why am I getting this error: TypeError: Input must be a 2D array

Tags: python-2.7, contour

I am working on a python code to plot Eddy Kinetic Energy. I am fairly new to python and I'm confused about an error I have been getting. I'm not worried about plotting my data on a map just yet, I just want to see if I can get it to plot. Here is my code and error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from pylab import *
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.cm as cm

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid
test = Dataset('p.34331101.atmos_daily.nc', 'r')

lat = test.variables['lat'][:]
lon = test.variables['lon'][:]
level = test.variables['level'][5]
time = test.variables['time'][:]
u = test.variables['ucomp'][:]
v = test.variables['vcomp'][:]
temp = test.variables['temp'][:]

print(lat.shape)
print(u.shape)
#uz = np.reshape(u, (30, 26, 90))
uzm = np.nanmean(u, axis=3)

#vz = np.reshape(v, (30, 26, 90))
vzm = np.nanmean(v, axis=3)
print(uzm.shape)

ustar = u-uzm[:,:,:,np.newaxis]
vstar = v-vzm[:,:,:,np.newaxis]

EKE = np.nanmean(.5*(ustar**2 + vstar**2), axis=3)

EKE1 = np.asarray(EKE)
%matplotlib inline

print(EKE.shape)

levels=[-10, -5, 0, 5, 10]
plt.contour(EKE[1,1,:])
#EKE is time, level, lat and the shape is (30, 26, 90)
```

**TypeError: Input must be a 2D array.**

Answer (score 0):

Bret, you would probably get more help if you included a bit more info with your error, did you not get a line number to look at?

I would hazard a guess that your problem is passing a 1D array to contour(). This sometimes seems counter-intuitive but numpy reduces the dimensions 'automatically' when you specify a single value in an index.

i.e. try

```
print(EKE.shape)
print(EKE[1,1,:].shape)
print(EKE[1:2,1:2,:].shape)
```